# Roblox Error: attempt to index local 'screengui' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, roblox

Workspace.Part.Script:16: attempt to index local 'screengui' (a nil value)

```
wait(2) -- Testing to make sure assets loaded

script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(hit)
    if not hit or not hit.Parent then return end
    local human = hit.Parent:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if human and human:IsA("Humanoid") then
        local person = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(human.parent)
        if not person then return end
        person.Checklist.FirstEggCollected.Value = true
        local playgui = person:FindFirstChild('PlayerGui')
        print(playgui)
        wait(0.2)
        local screengui = playgui:FindFirstChild('ScreenGui')
        wait(0.2)
        print(screengui) -- This prints nil
        local collectnotice = screengui:FindFirstChild('CollectionNotice') -- This is line 16
        local Toggle = collectnotice.Toggle
        local text = Toggle.Text
        local value = text.Value
        value = "The Easy Egg!"
        person:WaitForChild('PlayerGui'):FindFirstChild('ScreenGui'):FindFirstChild('CollectionNotice').Toggle.Color.Value = Color3.fromRGB(0,255,0)
        person:WaitForChild('PlayerGui'):FindFirstChild('ScreenGui'):FindFirstChild('CollectionNotice').Toggle.Value = true
        script.Parent:Destroy()
        wait(5)
        game.Workspace.Variables.IfFirstEggInGame.Value = false
    end
end)
```

I've been at this for hours. No idea how to make the error fix. FE is on, Yes its name is "ScreenGui" and it is inside "PlayerGui"

Error: Workspace.Part.Script:16: attempt to index local 'screengui' (a nil value)

Comment: Oh, and btw, It works perfectly in Studio, but not in the Game.

Answer (score 0):

From the Roblox manual: http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Instance/FindFirstChild

> Description: Returns the first child found with the given name, or nil
>   if no such child exists.

So there seems to be no child named "ScreenGui".

If a function may return nil you have to handle that properly. Blindly indexing possible nil values is bad practice.

Comment: Also, The scripts work exactly as they should in Roblox Studio. Roblox Studio runs on the **client side** which probably means that is the problem.

Comment: While In a game it runs **Server side**.

Comment: "Right click on StarterGui, mouse over Insert Object, and then click on ScreenGui." This is a quote from Roblox Developer "Intro to GUIs" explaining how to insert a ScreenGui. Because this is what I did, Means the way i'm indexing it is incorrect.

Comment: I think I figured it out. The problem was I was using Scripts. I noticed the errors came up on the Server side when Guis are only Client Objects. So my problem is I'm using Server-side scripts when I should be using Local scripts.

Comment: @King Maniac That's weird. It should have worked with a normal script as far as I know. Did making it a local script fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is at the line `local collectnotice = screengui:FindFirstChild('CollectionNotice')`.

You do not have an instance listed for the `screengui` variable.